# Unable to download Ubuntu SDK

Tags: installation, ubuntu-sdk

I am unable to download Ubuntu SDK . Whenever I try the command given on the [website](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/%5d).  I get an error saying `unable to lock the administration directory`.

Comment: Check these two cases:
Are you running an installation program in a different shell? Did you use sudo with the command?

Comment: No installation program was running and yes i used sudo with the command. I am gettin this error for every installation.

Comment: What command from what website? Are you using `sudo`? Could you copy the complete operation, from start to end. Edit your question and add the information, do not use comments (these are comments).

Comment: What exact command are you running?

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk

Comment: That website link is no longer available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run these three commands on the terminal to remove the lock

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```